# How can I convert a C++ enum to ctypes.Structure using Python 2.7.2?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, enums, ctypes

I have searched and searched, but I haven't found an example that does what I need to do.
I found 
[How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) 
here on SO, but it doesn't cover ctypes.Structure.
I also found 
[Using enums in ctypes.Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546355/using-enums-in-ctypes-structure)
here on SO, but it includes pointers, which I am not familiar with.

I have a header file that includes typedef enum, that I need to use in a ctypes.Structure in a Python file.

C++ header file:

```
typedef enum {

        ID_UNUSED,
        ID_DEVICE_NAME,
        ID_SCSI,
        ID_DEVICE_NUM,
} id_type_et;
```

Python file (The way I am currently doing it):

```
class IdTypeEt(ctypes.Structure):

        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [ ("ID_UNUSED", ctypes.c_int32),
            ("ID_DEVICE_NAME", ctypes.c_char*64),
            ("ID_SCSI", ctypes.c_int32),
            ("ID_DEVICE_NUM", ctypes.c_int32) ]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `enum` is not a structure, it's an integral type with a pre-defined set of values (the enumerator constants). It doesn't make sense to represent it with `ctypes.Structure`. You're looking for something like this:

```
from ctypes import c_int

id_type_et = c_int
ID_UNUSED = id_type_et(0)
ID_DEVICE_NAME = id_type_et(1)
ID_SCSI = id_type_et(2)
ID_DEVICE_NUM = id_type_et(3)
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the underlying values are always 0, 1, 2, 3, ... ?

Comment: @figs If the C++ header looks like the OP showed, yes. If the first enumerator is not given an explicit value, it's guaranteed to be 0. If a subsequent enumerator is not given an explicit value, it's guaranteed to be `previous enumerator + 1`.